C# .Net 8 AddMassTransit UsingRabbitMq with UseConsumeFilter
Got an error on adding UseConsumeFilter
[CS7069] Reference to type 'IConsumePipeConfigurator' claims it is defined in 'MassTransit', but it could not be found
My code
services.AddMassTransit(c =>
{
    c.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
       cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(HostConsumeFilter<>), context);
    }
}

HostConsumeFilter:
public class HostConsumeFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public HostConsumeFilter() { }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
}

MassTransit 8.2.2
MassTransit.RabbitMQ 8.2.2
I would like to add filter for all Consumers
Problem is
Two instances of one services works with one RabbitMQ.
But one instances have different code base to work with messages.
And I would like to separate messages between them.
Use In memory RabbitMq doesn't suit me

You have a dependency version mismatch with some other assembly referencing an older version of MassTransit.
